# JDialog not showing up on new computer?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I've been working on a fullscreen swing program and recently purchased a new laptop.

On this new laptop, the fonts don't show up the same in the program, which I assume means that font "MT Footlight light" didn't come installed on this computer. However, more importantly, the JDialog I created doesn't come to the front of the screen, even after calls to toFront() or requestFocus().

I could provide a SSCCE, but the code works fine on other computers I've used, that have the same OS (Windows 8) and different (Windows 7), so if anyone has any ideas where the problem could be originating please let me know

EDIT:

It's starting to look like it might not be the new computer, though I haven't really edited the parts with the JDialog, but here's a SSCCE of pretty much everything that affects the JDialog

```
public class Runner {
public static void main(String[] args){
    GraphicsEnvironment graphicsEnvironment = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice[] devices = graphicsEnvironment.getScreenDevices();
    new MainFrame(devices[0]);
}
}

public MainFrame(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice){
        super();
        this.setGraphicsDevice(graphicsDevice);
        this.setOrigDisplay(graphicsDevice.getDisplayMode()); 

    //Sets the panel to its default start screen, the main menu
    setPanel(new MainMenuPanel(this));

    //Resizes to full-screen
    if (graphicsDevice.isFullScreenSupported()){
        this.dispose();
        setUndecorated(true);
        setResizable(false);

        graphicsDevice.setFullScreenWindow(this);
        //this.setVisible(false);
        revalidate();  
    }else{
      System.out.println("Full-screen mode not supported");
    }  

    //Applies the custom theme
    try {
        Theme.loadTheme(new File("res/IS.theme"));
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new TinyLookAndFeel());
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setDynamicLayout(false);
    System.setProperty("sun.awt.noerasebackground", "true");
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

    Dimension size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    this.setBounds(0, 0, size.width, size.height);  


}
public class OptionsPanel extends JPanel{
     private final MainFrame context;
     private SetupDialog setup;

public OptionsPanel(final MainFrame m){
    super();
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    this.context = m;

    JButton setupButton = new JButton("Run set-up");
    setupButton.setFont(Constants.FONT_BIG);
    setupButton.setMargin(new Insets(20,20,20,20));
    setupButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            //TODO
            setup = new SetupDialog(context);

        }
    });
 //Other options stuff
}
}

public class SetupDialog extends JDialog{
private MainFrame context;
private JList<Info> midiSystemList;
private int instruction;
private NoteListener n;

public SetupDialog(MainFrame m){
    super(m);
    this.context = m;
    //setTitle("Set-up");
    this.setUndecorated(false);

    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);


    //Does setup stuff




    this.setUndecorated(true);
    pack();

    setModal(true);


    setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Comment: are you using same jdk implementation on both system?

Comment: I have eclipse and the jre on an external hard-drive so it should be

Comment: What happens if you run in the command line? Does it print any error messages?

Comment: No errors, I just retried it on a different computer again though, the fonts showed up fine but the JDialog is still buried, so I guess the error must be somewhere on my end, though I haven't edited that part of the code for a while so I figured it had something to do with the computer

Comment: *"I could provide a SSCCE,.."*  Do that.

Comment: Alright posted it, problem is somewhere in the last class because that is where the bring-to-front code is, it used to work I don't know what changed

Comment: I have funny feeling that while in full screen exclusive mode, you can't show other windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem by changing from actual fullscreen mode to a different kind by using

```
this.setExtendedState(JFrame.EXTENDED_BOTH);
this.setUndecorated(true);
```

I still am not sure what changed, since I was previously able to use JDialogs in regular fullscreen mode, but this solution works nonetheless